# Bundling MSI installers using Electron Build

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, desktop-application, electron-builder

I'm currently using Electron Builder to distribute a desktop application we are using in-house. For it to work I need to install ImageMagick and Ghostscript on the Windows systems where I'm going to install this app. I would like to make the installation seamless by having these programs install on the background somehow (or at least I want their MSI installers to popup during installation).

Is this currently feasible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to trigger custom scripts during install, so I ended up bundling the dependencies' executables as assets. When using Asar one must be careful to make sure that these dependencies are unpacked.

To get the native dependencies in a portable format one can use The Unarchiver on MacOS to explore the contents of MSI and NSIS installers. 7-Zip 15.05 can also open these.

Answer (score 1):

Run the command `electron-builder -p always --win` and it will generate the standalone windows installer named as `AppName Setup version.exe` in `dist` directory. As supporting your issue, you can create a zip file and host it somewhere. You can also use GitHub repository to host that zip file containing the required installer. Upon first open of app, download that zip file, extract in the background and you can execute it using `process. execFile` in node. Here is how to do it,

```js
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;

var fun =function(){
   console.log("fun() start");
   exec('imagic.exe', function(err, data) {  
        console.log(err)
        console.log(data.toString());                       
    });  
}
fun();
```

If you are looking for runtime installation of such file, You have to package and ship it with electron application. for shipping the static assets file with electron app you can read the post [here](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli/developing-electron-apps/electron-static-assets), It will help you to serve the static assets with app.

Comment: This builds the application, but doesn't bundle the dependencies I mentioned.